# Operator '[]' is not applicable to an Undef Value

Tags: puppet

```
[tom@pe-server] cat site.pp
node 'mynode.com' {
    include base::common::setup

    $svn_url_disable_uac = {
        svn_co_dir => 'automation/scripts/base/common',
        svn_url    => 'abc/trunk/automation/chv/modules/base/files/common/disable_uac.ps1',
    }
}
```

---

```
[tom@pe-server] cat disable_uac.pp
class base::common::disable_uac inherits base::common::param {
    base::common::svn::repo_checkout { 'Copy disable_uac PS script':
        svn_url_params => $svn_url_disable_uac,
    }

    util::executeps { 'Disable UAC':
        pspath    => $disable_uac,
        argument  => '',
        subscribe => Base::Common::Svn::Repo_checkout['Copy disable_uac PS script'],
    }
}
```

---

```
[tom@pe-server] cat setup.pp
class base::common::setup inherits base::common::param {
    include base::common::disable_uac
}
```

---

```
[tom@pe-server] cat param.pp
class base::common::param (
    $repo_checkout_ps = 'C:/puppet/automation/scripts/infra/repo_checkout.ps1',
    $disable_uac = 'C:/puppet/automation/scripts/base/common/disable_uac.ps1',
) {}
```

---

When i run the above code, i get the following error:

```
Error:
Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Operator '[]' is not applicable to an Undef Value. 
at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/client/modules/base/manifests/common/svn/repo_checkout.pp:7:19 
at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/client/modules/base/manifests/common/disable_uac.pp:2 on node mynode.com
```

---

One thing to note is that if i move the following code from `base::common::disable_uac` to `site.pp`, then everything works fine:

```
   base::common::svn::repo_checkout { 'Copy disable_uac PS script':
        svn_url_params => $svn_url_disable_uac,
    }
```

UPDATE:
Sorry, i missed putting that part in the post. Here it is:

```
[tom@pe-server] cat repo_checkout.pp
define base::common::svn::repo_checkout (
    $svn_url_params,
) {
    include base::common::param
    $repo_checkout_ps = $base::common::param::repo_checkout_ps

    $svn_co_dir = $svn_url_params[svn_co_dir]    # Line 7
    $svn_url = $svn_url_params[svn_url]

    util::executeps { "Checking out build packet for URL \"$svn_url\"":
        pspath   => $repo_checkout_ps,
        argument => "\"$svn_co_dir\" \"$svn_url\"",
    }
}
```

---

I've spent few hours looking into it but unable to figure out the issue.

Comment: There is some spaghetti code going on here. I recommend a redesign to simplify your structure, which will probably also fix your issue. Are you using a recent version of Puppet? Module data could also fix your issue and help you purge that `params` inheritance from your design.

Comment: I can't agree more that it's a mess but unfortunately few in our team find it as the `correct` approach and i'm done explaining for the time being. Till the next iteration, i have to live with it. Still, what i don't understand is why the `Undef` value error is coming? In `site.pp`, i am including `setup` module, which in turn includes `disable_uac` module. Both `setup` and `disable_uac` modules are inheriting parameters in their respective modules but still the value seem to be Undef.

Comment: Showing `base::svn::repo_checkout` up through line 7 and whatever afterward to close off the code may be helpful to see what is being undef and why.

Comment: Please check the UPDATE section.

Comment: So the thing that jumps out at me is that the parameter is assigned to as `$disable_uac` in `param.pp`, but referenced as `$svn_url_disable_uac` in `disable_uac.pp`. That could result in an undefined parameter for `svn_url_params`. It might be assigned somewhere other than just in the param and therefore be available at a different scope when you put it in your `site.pp`.

Comment: `$disable_uac` is not being referenced as `$svn_url_disable_uac`. Actually, what `disable_uac.pp` is meant to do is 1) Copy the Powershell script to agent box (which is taken care by passing a `hash of params` in `site.pp` to the variable `$svn_url_disable_uac`). This variable is then passed on to `base::common::svn::repo_checkout` which is present in `disable_uac.pp` script. 2) Next part in `disable_uac.pp` is executing the script (`$disable_uac`) on the remote instance.